# React swiper not working: Uncaught TypeError: react_1.useEffect is not a function

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I have installed react-id-swiper in my web app following this tuts:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-id-swiper

Installation:
`npm install --save react-id-swiper@latest swiper@latest`

And I have created following component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Swiper from 'react-id-swiper/lib/ReactIdSwiper.full';

const SimpleSwiper = () => (
  <Swiper>
    <div>Slide 1</div>
    <div>Slide 2</div>
    <div>Slide 3</div>
    <div>Slide 4</div>
    <div>Slide 5</div>
  </Swiper>
)

export default SimpleSwiper;
```

Have imported component in App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import LandingPage from './templates/LandingPage';
import SimpleSwiper from "./templates/Swiper";

class App extends React.Component{

  render(){
    return(

    <div>
      <Route path="/" exact component={LandingPage} />
      <Route path="/slide" component={ () => 
        <SimpleSwiper />}  
      />
    </div>
  )
  }

}

export default App;
```

When I access it in browser `http://localhost:3000/slide`
the following error is displayed:

```
Uncaught TypeError: react_1.useEffect is not a function
    at ReactIdSwiper (ReactIdSwiper.full.js:104)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:13381)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:13821)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:15864)
    at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:15903)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:100)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:138)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:187)
    at replayUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:15311)
    at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:15963)
```

I am not sure what I have missed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I was using 16.3.2 version of React.

Hooks are released as a part of version 16.8.0 and you can use it by upgrading React and React-dom 16.8.0.

**I have upgraded it:**

`npm upgrade react react-dom`

Version that was updated to is `"react-dom": "^16.8.6"` and everything works great now.

So if you want to use react-swiper make sure your React and React-dom is up to date so Hooks can be used.

Comment: AHHH damn, my useEffect didn't work cause it doesn't exist in the version you were using..  Should have asked that first lol!  Nice job!

Comment: Yes :D but I had no clue that was issue. Tnx mate!

Comment: Honestly, your answer probably just saved a ton of people some time.  Sooner or later all these people are going to want to try hooks in their old projects and will run into this problem.

Comment: Thanks! It took me some time to figure out what is going on. Will be happy if it helps to someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently they are using the useEffect hooks already (awesome!).  Maybe you can import it directly?

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
```

Comment: Yes, the same thing crossed my mind also but no, it's not working :/  I have found another solution upgrading react-dom. I have explained it in **edit**. It works fine now :) Error was because I was not able to use hooks.